# Taskbar Compact Mode?

Tags: c#, windows, media-player, mode, minimize

I have an idea for a project that I want to do. However, doing it would require for me to be able to minimize to a compact mode similar to the compact mode that Windows Media Player has. Is this possible and how would I do it?

Comment: Are you using WinForms, or WPF? What have you tried so far? I'm not sure what Media Player's compact mode looks like - can you add a screenshot?

Comment: I don't think there is anything special about it. Just provide a smaller version of your main view.

Comment: What you are searching for is a Windows taskbar toolbar, aka a "deskbar". Windows has a built-in way to define them for folders, and there obviously must be a way to set up applications with custom deskbars, but this does not seem to be well-explored by custom developers (and will apparently be pretty moot as of Windows 8 anyway).

Comment: Note that shell extensions should not be written in managed code.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming I understand correctly what you need, the term you are looking for is "deskband" and it is possible to achieve something like this with C# with the usage of the win API.

Take a look at the resources bellow.

1. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144099%28v=vs.85%29.aspx - mainly information
2. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2219/Extending-Explorer-with-Band-Objects-using-NET-and - a working example